# How do i shorten the data-text appear in my post for my website

Tags: php, character

I am trying to adjust the character display of a post in my website, but no matter how I change the codes. it either cuts off to 1 word or have an error. please help on this, what should i do?

Here are the codes.

```
<p style="float:right; margin-top:3px;width:88px;">       
    {if $short_urls eq "1" OR $short_urls eq "2"}
            {insert name=get_short_url value=a assign=takento PID=$posts[i].PID SEO=$posts[i].name}

            <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{$takento}" data-via="{$twitter}" data-hashtags="DailyRantz" data-text="{insert name=strip_special2 value=a assign=cstory2 text=$posts[i].story}{$cstory2}", data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>
            {else}

            <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{$baseurl}/view/{$posts[i].name|stripslashes|replace:' ':'+'}/" data-via="{$twitter}" data-text="You know,.......Want to know my Daily Rantz? Join me and others @" data-count="horizontal" data-hashtags="DailyRantz">Tweet</a>
            {/if}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
        </p>
```

I did add in the codes, however it's not working for me. Anyone have a clue what i did do wrong?

```
<div style="float:right;">

        <p style="float:left; margin-top:4px; margin-right:10px;">
            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="plusToggle('{$posts[i].PID}');"><img src="{$imageurl}/plus_mini.gif"></a>
        </p>
```

{literal}

```
        <p style="float:right; margin-top:3px;width:88px;">       
    {if $short_urls eq "1" OR $short_urls eq "2"}
            {$smarty->assign{'$post[i].PID'}|truncate:100:'...':True; 

            {insert name=get_short_url value=a assign=takento PID=$posts[i].PID SEO=$posts[i].name}

            <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{$takento}" data-via="{$twitter}" data-hashtags="DailyRantz" data-text="{insert name=strip_special2 value=a assign=cstory2 text=$posts[i].story}{$cstory2}", data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>

            {else}

            <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{$baseurl}/view/{$posts[i].name|stripslashes|replace:' ':'+'}/" data-via="{$twitter}" data-text="You know,...Want to know my Daily Rantz? Join me and others @" data-count="horizontal" data-hashtags="DailyRantz">Tweet</a>
            {/if}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
        </p>
```

Please help, thanks alot for your times.

Comment: I'm using smarty language with php for this site.

Comment: Then you can use truncate function - http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{$str|truncate:20}`

it will trucnate the string ref : smarty truncate.

Usually to show a string we will be using `{$string}` in smarty

If you want to truncate the string `{$string|truncate:20:...}` use it like this

You do this only at the place were you are displaying it not while assigning.

ie `{$smarty->assign{'$post[i].PID'}|truncate:100:'...':True;` will not work.

NOTE : Check the syntax for `$smarty->assign` , it needs a variable name to which you are assigning and a value you are assiging.

So as a complete code it will be like this :

```
1. First assign a value to a variable.
    $smarty->{assign var="name" value="just to test"}
    ref: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl

 2. truncate the value.
    {$name|truncate:20:...}
    ref: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl
```

Comment: Erm, i'm not really very good in smarty language. Could you teach me where should i include the truncate?

Comment: wer is your post dispalyed, just use it there. ref : http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl

Comment: it will be displayed in a pop-up box for people to tweet about it in twitter. So you have any clue where should i place the code?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra please be as kind as to provide at least one full line so as OP can see _how_ he can use this, not just _what_ he needs to use!

Comment: @ppeterka : In question(code), he has not mentioned were he has to truncate, else i would have added the code. again it is a simple function those who know little smarty can understand it.

Comment: i need to truncate at the area where the twitter pop up appear so as to shorten the character shown to users. like a sneak preview of post. Please help me to see where did i go wrong?

Comment: Thank you Prasanth! Sorry to trouble you cause it's my first time using smarty.

Comment: @WooJieZhung : Its fine, happy to help you.